# Value of type '[UILabel]' has no member 'numberOfLines'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I'm using Swift.

The text for my descriptions are being cut off. I would like all of the text to be showing, but when I add numberOfLines = 0 I get an error.

"Value of type '[UILabel]' has no member 'numberOfLines'"

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class SurveyResultsViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var lblSortedScores       : [UILabel]!
    @IBOutlet var sortedTitle           : [UILabel]!

    @IBOutlet var sortedDescription     : [UILabel]! {
        didSet {
            sortedDescription.numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var cellFinishButton : UITableViewCell!

    var survey: LikertSurvey?
    var points = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    var results: [(Int, Int)] = []


    var descriptionLabels =
        [("Money Avoiders think that money is bad and that rich people are greedy. They often feel like they don't deserve to have money.\n\nAvoiders may have a hard time sticking to a budget, can be compulsive buyers at times, and would rather not look at their bank statements."),
        ("Money Worshippers believe that money will make them happier and solve their problems, but they will never have enough of it.\n\nWorshippers are likely to overspend or have credit card debt. They also may overwork themselves at the expense of close relationships. "),
        ("People with the Money Status belief see money as a way of achieving higher status. They can believe their self worth is tied to their net worth.\n\nThose may lie about money, pretend to be richer than they are, and take on risks to make money quickly. "),
        ("Those with the Money Viligance belief believe in saving money. They can often be anxious and secretive about their finances.\n\nThey may be overly wary of their finances and scared to buy anything on credit.")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(points, forKey: "points")

        self.setResults()
        self.initUI()


    }



    private func setResults() {
        for (index, point) in points.enumerated() {
            results.append((index, point))
        }

        results.sort { (result1, result2) -> Bool in
            return result1.1 > result2.1
        }
    }

    private func initUI() {
        for i in 0 ..< results.count {
            let title = survey!.questionCategories[results[i].0]
            let description = descriptionLabels[results[i].0]
            lblSortedScores[i].text = "\(results[i].1) points"
            sortedTitle[i].text = "\(title)"
            sortedDescription[i].text = "\(description)"

        }

        let finishButtonTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.finishButtonTapped(_:)))
        cellFinishButton.addGestureRecognizer(finishButtonTap)

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

    }

    @objc func finishButtonTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.survey?.completed = true
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulations! You earned 100 XP from completing this quest!", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

                     alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
                                                             style: .default) { action in
                         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToSectionTableView", sender: self)
                     })

                     self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

If it's because the UILabel is in brackets how can I work around this? When I remove them, I just get more errors.

[image]

Comment: Did you really mean for your outlets to be arrays of labels?  Did you accidentally create a new referencing outlet collection instead of a new referencing outlet in your storyboard?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, not sure if I need them. I updated the post to show you that end up getting more errors

Comment: You need to determine if you really wanted an array of labels - In which case you need to access each label from the array as per the other answers, or if you only wanted a single label, in which case you need to ensure that the rest of your code also only uses a single label. From the looks of your initUI code, perhaps you do want an array of labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `sortedDescription` is of type `[UILabel]` - an array of `UILabel`'s. The `UILabel` class has the property `numberOfLines` and not the Array class.

If you want to set the `numberOfLines` for each `UILabel` in the `sortedDescription` array, try something like this:

```
var sortedDescription: [UILabel]! {
      didSet {
        for label in sortedDescription {
          label.numberOfLines = 0
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy your code and run, i explore some errors. First

```
@IBOutlet var sortedDescription     : [UILabel]! {
        didSet {
            sortedDescription.numberOfLines = 0
        }
 }
```

Array of UILabel don't have numberOfLines. You should change to this

```
@IBOutlet var sortedDescription     : [UILabel]! {
        didSet {
            sortedDescription.forEach({ (label) in
                label.numberOfLines = 0
            })
        }
 }
```